# How to turn a for-loop for turtle graphic shape into a recursive function in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, recursion, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to create a function that repeats a shape to make a pattern using turtle graphics. I'm not sure how I could change my code to make into a recursive function so that I don't need to use a for-loop to create every step.

So far, I've created the general shape in the middle and I'm in the process of creating the pattern:

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
t2 = turtle.Turtle()
t3 = turtle.Turtle()
t4 = turtle.Turtle()
t5 = turtle.Turtle()
t6 = turtle.Turtle()
t7 = turtle.Turtle()
t8 = turtle.Turtle()
t9 = turtle.Turtle()
t10 = turtle.Turtle()
t11 = turtle.Turtle()
t12 = turtle.Turtle()
for i in (t,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12):
    i.speed(10)
def hex(rep):
    if rep > 1:
        for i in range(6):
            t.forward(50)
            t.left(60)
        t.right(90)
        t2.forward(50)
        t2.right(90)
        t3.forward(50)
        t3.right(30)
       for i in range(2):
            for a in (t4, t5):
                a.forward(50)
                a.left(60)
      t4.right(150)
      t5.right(90)
      for i in range(3):
            for a in (t6, t7):
                a.forward(50)
                a.left(60)
      t6.right(150)
      t7.right(90)
      for i in range(4):
           for a in (t8, t9):
                a.forward(50)
                a.left(60)
      t8.right(150)
      t9.right(90)
      for i in range(5):
           for a in (t10, t11):
               a.forward(50)
               a.left(60)
      t10.right(150)
      t11.right(90)
      t12.left(210)

      for i in (t,t2,t3,t4,t5,t6,t7,t8,t9,t10,t11,t12):
          i.forward(50)

      t.left(90)
      for i in range(12):
          t.forward(50)
          t.left(30)
      t.right(90)
      for i in (t,t3,t5,t7,t9,t11):
           for a in range(9):
               i.right(30)
               i.forward(50)

hex(2)
```

The end result should be a pattern that looks like this:

http://www.gwydir.demon.co.uk/jo/tess/bighexsqtri.gif

Answer (score 0):

In the spirit of, "why use twelve turtles when one will do", here's my recursive solution to your problem:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

RADIUS = 100
SIDES = 12
EXTENT = 360 / 12

def pattern(repetitions):
    turtle.right(EXTENT/2)

    for segment in range(12):
        turtle.circle(RADIUS, EXTENT, 1)

        if repetitions and segment % 2 == 0:
            heading = turtle.heading()
            position = turtle.position()

            turtle.right(90 - EXTENT/2)

            pattern(repetitions - 1)

            turtle.setposition(position)
            turtle.setheading(heading)

screen = Screen()
turtle = Turtle(visible=False)

turtle.penup()
turtle.goto(-RADIUS/4, -RADIUS)  # roughly center drawing on window
turtle.pendown()

screen.tracer(False)  # because I have no patience!
pattern(4)
screen.tracer(True)

screen.exitonclick()
```

The drawing here is not optimal, and could use work, as it does redrawing of lines which is always best avoided.  (I don't mean just lifting the pen, but avoiding the need to traverse the line again.)

Also note that `hex()` is the name of a Python built-in function so you shouldn't use it for your own program.